# OrmLite Generic create method

Tags: java, generics, ormlite

I want to include a create method for each BO that extends the abstract class `BusinessObject`. I came up with the method shown below, but at compile time I get the following exception at the `createDao(...)` statement:

```
'invalid inferred types for D; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)'
```

This is what the create method looks like.

```
public abstract class BusinessObject {

    ...

    public <T extends BusinessObject> T create(T bo) throws InstantiationException, SQLException,
        NamingException {

        final Dao<T, Long> dao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), bo.getClass());

        bo.setTimestampAdded(System.currentTimeMillis());
        bo.setTimestampModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
        bo.setDateAdded(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        bo.setDateModified(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        dao.create(bo);

        return bo;
    }
}
```

While on the subject, maybe someone can also link me to a decent, comprehensive tutorial on the matter of generics. There's a lot of basic tutorials out there but not much about intermediate stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have been playing around a little and found out that changing the method signature to include the inferred class is the key.

```
public <T extends BusinessObject> T create(T bo, Class<T> cls) throws InstantiationException,
        SQLException, NamingException {

    final Dao<T, Long> dao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), cls);

    bo.setTimestampAdded(System.currentTimeMillis());
    bo.setTimestampModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
    bo.setDateAdded(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    bo.setDateModified(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    dao.create(bo);

    return bo;
}
```

The reason is that `getClass()` returns `Class<?>` whereas `createDao(...)` expects `Class<T>`. I wonder if it is possible to cast `Class<?>` to `Class<T>`. Eclipse however spits out a warning:

'Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class to Class'